# C++ MFC create new dialog and add Combobox item

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I'm using MFC to build an application with two dialogs.
When I press a button in the parent dialog a new window including a Combobox should apprear.

I created a first dialog with a button "New". This button will open the second dialog.
Therefor I created a second dialog with a Combobox. The Combobox has a linked variable `variableCombobox`. The second class is called `CSecond`.

Before I do anything in the new dialog I want to add an item to the Combobox.
In the first dialog class I create the new window like this:

```
void CFirstDlg::OnBnClickedNew()
{
    CSecond dlg2 = new CSecond();
    dlg2.variableCombobox.AddString(L"test");
    dlg2.DoModal();
}
```

The program crashes in the line I want to add the `test` string to the Combobox showing an assertion error.
I noticed that the `dlg2` object is `null` but I don't know why.

Can anyone tell me how to create a second window immediately adding an new item in the Combobox of the second window?

Comment: Your code looks incorrect.  'Newing' a class returns a pointer.  You have not declared 'dlg2' as a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the line to
CSecond *dlg2 = new CSecond();

and dlg2-> instead of dlg2. ...
I still get the assertion error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the second dialog is a modal dialog. The windows does not exist before the call to `DoModal()` and no longer exist after that function returns. Therefore calling `AddString` on the combobox is not all right, since the combo box does not exist at that time.

The solution is to initialize the dialog with your desired values (like in the constructor for instance, or other methods) and then in `OnInitDialog()` use those values to setup the controls (including this call to `AddString` for the combobox).

Comment: That did it. Thank you for your fast reply and the solution